# Importing from Web, no UTF-8

Tags: excel

I'm importing a Sheet from Google Sheets to Excel using in Google Sheets option to Publish in Internet. Then in Excel I use Get data from the Web. I copy link from the Google Sheets. And everything works but there are no UTF-8 symbols. There are things like this:

```
â‚¬ĂłÄ…Ĺ›Ĺ‚ĹĽĹşÄ‡e
```

How can I change it to work properly?

Comment: [Here is a good site](https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-import-csv-file-uses-utf-8-character-encoding-0) which discusses how to import a CSV file into Excel which is UTF-8 encoded.  Google is your friend.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not importing a CSV file but a link to Google Sheet.